# How to get label text value form a html page?

Tags: javascript

I have a html page , where the html is rendered as :

```
<div id = 'mViB'>
<table id = 'myTable'>
<tbody>
<tr> ...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr> ...</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="*spaM4" for="*zigField4">
All hell.
<span class = 'msde32'></span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Now what i want to do is get the label text 'All hell.' from the label.

For that purpose i have used both  : `document.getElementById('*spaM4').text` and `document.getElementById('*spaM4').value`  but incidentally none of them worked.

I have used `document.getElementById('*spaM4').innerHTML`  but that returns the `span class` as well, but i just want to get the text .

Unfortunately, the asterisks in element IDs are 3rd party code and I cannot change it.

Can any one suggest any other way for getting the label text ?

Comment: its document.getElementById('spaM4').innerHTML;
remove * from id

Comment: Don't use asteriks in IDs, would you?

Comment: @DavidJashi : They can be used, that's not a problem, some times  for categorization and indexing, asterisk is used .

Comment: Asterisks are bad to use because of the wildcard conflict... I think?

Comment: @obitusis : Yes , that is correct, but unfortunately it's a 3rd party code and i cannot change it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('*spaM4').textContent
```

If you need to target < IE9 then you need to use `.innerText`

Answer (score 18):

This will get what you want in plain JS.

```
var el = document.getElementById('*spaM4');
text = (el.innerText || el.textContent);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uVzz3/)**

Comment: You could add `/\s{2,}/g.replace(text, ' ')` to normalize the white space.

Comment: Thanks. `innerText` did not work in mozilla, but `textContent` did . +1

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, great. Happy it was useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can use textContent attribute to retrieve data from a label.

```
 <script>
       var datas = document.getElementById("excel-data-div").textContent;
    </script>


<label id="excel-data-div" style="display: none;">
     Sample text
</label>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent):

```
  var el = document.getElementById('*spaM4');
  console.log(el.innerText || el.textContent);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NeTgC/2/

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for the useful fiddle .

Answer (score 5):

The best way to get the text value from a `<label>` element is as follows.

if you will be getting element ids frequently it's best to have a function to return the ids:

```
function id(e){return document.getElementById(e)}
```

Assume the following structure:
    `<label for='phone'>Phone number</label>
    <input type='text' id='phone' placeholder='Mobile or landline numbers...'>`

This code will extract the text value 'Phone number' from the`<label>: 
    var text = id('phone').previousElementSibling.innerHTML;`

This code works on all browsers, and you don't have to give each`<label>`element a unique id.

Comment: You can also use `previousElementSibling.textContent' as modern browsers, including Firefox, recognise this format.

Comment: relying on element order is dangerous and error prone

Answer (score 3):

For cases where the data **element is inside the label** like in this example:

```
<label for="subscription">Subscription period
    <select id='subscription' name='subscription'>
        <option></option>
        <option>1 year</option>
        <option>2 years</option>
        <option>3 years</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

all the previous answers will give an **unexpected result**:

```
"Subscription period


                    1 year
                    2 years
                    3 years

            "
```

While the **expected result** would be:

```
"Subscription period"
```

So, the **correct solution** will be like this:

```
const label = document.getElementById('yourLableId');
const labelText = Array.prototype.filter
    .call(label.childNodes, x => x.nodeName === "#text")
    .map(x => x.textContent)
    .join(" ")
    .trim();
```

Comment: Nice attempt, but this won't work if the label contains spans

Comment: Yes, it's not a universal solution as well. Usually, a particular solution is required for a particular case. This worked for my case, so I didn't go further. You can edit and improve my answer if you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lbltext = document.getElementById('*spaM4').innerHTML
```