# How to fetch the text of a Label in html

Tags: html, dom, getelementbyid

I have used document.getElementById('Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label') and got this piece of HTML as a result.

`<span id="Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label" title="" style="padding-left:7px; word-break:break-word;  border:0px;" class="inputLabelStyle checkbox-label  " for="444d0dd5">Card Option A </span>`

Now I want to get the value "Card Option A". But `document.getElementById('Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label').text; document.getElementById('Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label').value; document.getElementById('Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label').innerHTML; document.getElementById('Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label').label;`

None of them are returning the desired output. how can I fetch "Card Option A" with document.getElementById concept?

Comment: Try using .textContent found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943164/10393765

Comment: Could you please post the HTML of the Select which you are using? with the above HTML which you posted. ```document.getElementById('Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label').innerHTML;``` should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Get it by using JQuery `$("#Q_GENCREDITCARDAPPLN_CMPLX_label").text();`